# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter

Tags: eclipse, grails

Me he instalado la nueva versión de Grails 3.1.6 y estoy utilizando Eclipse Mars 2 Release (4.5.2). Cuando intento crear un nuevo proyecto Grails me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Command terminated with an exception: org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died (see details for partial output)
Grails process died
------System.out:-----------

------System.err:-----------
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

¿Alguien puede decirme qué estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Verifica que tienes la clase `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter` en tus librerías

Comment: Diría que no la tengo. Me he bajado Grails 3.1.6 desde la página oficial (https://grails.org/download.html), pero no está em ninguna de las librerías ¿Alguna idea de dónde puedo conseguir la librería que contenga la clase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he seguido los pasos de esta [página web](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/eclipse-mars-grails-3-1-with-gradle-groovy-and-gsp-support/)

He creado un proyecto grails usando la línea de comandos y lo he importado a Eclipse como proyecto Gradle. No es lo mismo que con la versión anterior de Grails, pero funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Estás intentando crear el proyecto desde Eclipse? Grails 3.x es bastante diferente a 2.x y los IDE no soportan bien las versiones nuevas de grails (ni Intelij, ni GGTS tampoco)

Yo diría que intentaras crear el proyecto utilizando la linea de comandos ejecutando `grails create-app`.

Otra cosa que validaría es que efectivamente la linea de comandos este utilizando la versión de grails deseada (en este caso la 3.1.6). Para el manejo de versiones de grails por linea de comandos te recomiendo la siguiente herramienta http://sdkman.io/.

Luego de instalada te permite switchear entre versiones de grails de una manera muy práctica, algo así como:

`$ sdk use grails 2.4.4`

Para usar la versión 2.4.4 (ejemplificando) y luego si quiero cambiar y usar otra versión simplemente

`$ sdk use grails 3.1.6`

Espero sirva la respuesta, saludos